# Elastic Stack CSV Year Column

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to import a CSV that has a Year column in the format YYYY. It's not a full date.

I wanted to use this as my X-Axis for a visiualization in Kibana. So far I am treating it as an integer. My Graph looks terrible as it seems to include many values that aren't in the data.

[image]

How do I best handle this sort of data in logstash? Should I be processing it as a date despite it not being a full date? What would the config look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by this. I've tried it out with the following example data:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "year": 2010,
  "length": 100
}
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "year": 2011,
  "length": 110
}
PUT test/_doc/3
{
  "year": 2012,
  "length": 105
}
```

And the result looks by default like you'd expect it to look (including the y-axis config):

[image]

And here is the x-axis. No other values changed and it's generally pretty much the default config of a line chart.

[image]